# Problem in displaying the Marker values in MPandroid barchart

Tags: android

The below code which implement markerview in `Android` barchart

[image: difference of marker values in chart and below table]

Answer (score 0):

public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

```
    private final TextView tvContent;

    public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    // runs every time the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

        if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

            CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

            tvContent.setText(Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, false));
        } else {
            tvContent.setText(Utils.formatNumber(e.getY(), 0, false));
        }

        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    private MPPointF mpPointF;

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {

        if(mpPointF == null){
            mpPointF = new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
        }
        return mpPointF;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using above code......If values are above 10million values are showing as above image